# Unable to open playwright HTML Report (using Docker)

Tags: docker, playwright, playwright-test

I have pulled the image using below command into my root of the project

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.24.2-focal
```

and then run the image using below command:

```
docker run -it --rm --ipc=host mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.24.2-focal /bin/bash
```

and it takes me to the container (please check screenshot below)

[image]

when I run the command **npx playwright test** my all test got passed but when I tried to open test report using command: **npx playwright show-report** then it shows me below result:

[image]

It says:

> Failed to open browser on http://127.0.0.1:9323

What can I try to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Playwright tries to open the HTML report inside your Docker container, but that is not working since you don't have a browser with a GUI inside the container. Set "open: never" inside your config and manually open the HTML report on your host via double click on the playwright-report/index.html site. See here https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters#html-reporter

Comment: Hi halfer, thankyou for the tip. I have one more question to that I have different folder in my project containing backend and frontend and while I am in the container as I mentioned above the test files are not created in my pr
oject rather it is created inside the container(pls check screenshot) I have attached.

the problem is how to work here with these files because these files are not created into my project?

Comment: How I can create those files inside my project so I can create tests and open my test reports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Max is right, you have to add for example in your playwright.config.ts the option `open: 'never'`. For example:

```js
const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  // (...)
  reporter: [ ['html', { open: 'never'}], ['list'] ],
  // (...)
}
```

And to answer to your second question, about getting the reports on your host, you have to use a volume when executing `docker run`.

For example, let's say that on your host, in your current folder, you have your playwright.config.ts file, then run the following command to mount the whole directory on the container:

```bash
docker run -it --rm --ipc=host \
  --workdir=/my_tests \
  -v $PWD:/my_tests \
  mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.24.2-focal bash
```